# Taking all logged in users and printing those who has running mail

Tags: linux, ksh

Good mornin'
So I'm trying to print all users that have mail running on their terminals. I managed to get usernames from finger and redirect it to variable 'i'. User in our system have names like d123456.

```
for i in `finger | grep '^d......' -o`;
do
  export a=`ps -U $i | grep 'mail' -o`;
  if $a = "mail"; then
    echo $i;
  fi;
echo $a;
echo $i;
done
```

I expect it to just print usernames of users with running mail.

Comment: Try something without a loop or `finger` and call `ps -ef` for information for all users. Or start with `ps -eo user,cmd | grep "[m]ail"`. The brackets around `[m]` are added to avoid finding the `grep` command. It is hard to tell the correct string to search for, avoiding `vi mailinglist.cfg` and finding `/usr/bin/mail`.

Comment: Does `fuser -u /usr/bin/mail` work for you (after some filtering like `fuser -u /usr/bin/mail 2>&1 | sed 's/[^(]*(\([^)]*\))/\1 /g'`) ?